# MySQL - On Duplicate Key Update another column with old column value

Tags: mysql, sql-update, on-duplicate-key

I do not know how to deal with a simple problem. My MySQL Database contains data about latitude and longitude points collection. My target is to calculate the distance and direction during the update of the row.

This is what I am inserting right now:

```
INSERT INTO positions 
            (NAME, 
             lat, 
             longitude, 
             update_at) 
VALUES      ( 'Object 1', 
              '50.123456', 
              '20.123456', 
              '2020-05-27 18:07:26')
```

This query is updated every minute but there are a lot of individual objects. To make it simple I am implementing `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Right now the query looks like below:

```
INSERT INTO positions 
            ( 
                        NAME , 
                        latitude , 
                        longitude , 
                        update_at 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                        'Object 1' , 
                        '50.123456' , 
                        '20.123456' , 
                        '2020-05-27 18:07:26' 
            ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
              name = VALUES(NAME), 
              lat = VALUES(latitude),
              lon = VALUES(longitude), 
              update_at = VALUES(update_at)
```

This is the moment when I want firstly store the `old_latitude` and `old_longitude` values during the update. The first question is:

**How to get old value during the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?**

I want to store this data because sometimes I do not want to upload old values. Especially when the distance between two points is smaller than, for example, 10 meters.

If the value has longer distance I want to calculate direction.

**The overall question is how to implement that case in the easiest way in MySQL query?**

I will be glad for some suggestions or help! :)

EDIT:
The simple step by step Minimal Reproducible Example:

**The Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Positions (
       name VCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
       lat DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL,
       lon DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL,
       update_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

**The first step:**

```
 INSERT INTO positions 
            (NAME, 
             lat, 
             longitude, 
             update_at) 

 VALUES 
            ( 'Obj1'
            , '50.123456'
            , '20.123456'
            , '2020-05-27 10:00:00')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE name = VALUES(name)
            , latitude = VALUES(lat)
            , longitude = VALUES(lon)
            , update_at = VALUES(update_at)
            , IF(distance(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon)>10, (
                 old_lat = OLD_VALUES(lat)
               , old_lon = OLD_VALUES(lon),
               , dir = direction(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon))
         ))
```

**The Result:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| name |  lat |  lon | update_at | old_lat | old_lon| dir |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Obj1 | 50.1 | 21.1 |2020-05-27 |    0    |   0    |  0  |
|      |      |      | 10:00:00  |         |        |     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**The second step:**

```
 INSERT INTO positions 
            (NAME, 
             lat, 
             longitude, 
             update_at) 
 VALUES 
            ( 'Obj1'
            , '52.123456'
            , '25.123456'
            , '2020-05-27 11:00:00'),
            ( 'Obj2'
            , '32.123456'
            , '15.123456'
            , '2020-05-27 12:00:00'),
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE name = VALUES(name)
            , latitude = VALUES(lat)
            , longitude = VALUES(lon)
            , update_at = VALUES(update_at)
            , IF(distance(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon)>10, (
                old_lat = OLD_VALUES(lat)
               , old_lon = OLD_VALUES(lon),
               , dir = direction(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon))
         ))
```

**The Result:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| name |  lat |  lon | update_at | old_lat | old_lon| dir |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Obj1 | 52.1 | 25.1 |2020-05-27 |   50.1  |   21.1 |  20 |
|      |      |      | 11:00:00  |         |        |     |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Obj2 | 32.1 | 15.1 |2020-05-27 |    0    |    0   |  0  |
|      |      |      | 12:00:00  |         |        |     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**The third step:**

```
 INSERT INTO positions 
            (NAME, 
             lat, 
             longitude, 
             update_at) 
  VALUES 
            ( 'Obj1'
            , '52.987654'
            , '25.987654'
            , '2020-05-27 13:00:00'),
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE name = VALUES(name)
            , latitude = VALUES(lat)
            , longitude = VALUES(lon)
            , update_at = VALUES(update_at)
            , IF(distance(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon)>10, (
                 old_lat = OLD_VALUES(lat)
               , old_lon = OLD_VALUES(lon),
               , dir = direction(VALUES(lat), VALUES(lon), OLD_VALUES(lat), OLD_VALUES(lon))
         ))
```

**The Result:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| name |  lat |  lon | update_at | old_lat | old_lon| dir |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Obj1 | 52.9 | 25.9 |2020-05-27 |   50.1  |  21.1  |  20 |
|      |      |      | 13:00:00  |         |        |     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Obj2 | 32.1 | 15.1 |2020-05-27 |    0    |   0    |  0  |
|      |      |      | 12:00:00  |         |        |     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint :). I've added the example of the functionality that I want to receive.

Comment: I've added the Table description and format the queries better. Hopefully, the question will be better right now.